# Commissioned to build a row of lights, want to make sure I'm doing it right/ no easier way

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I'm building a set for a theater group and they want me to build a row of lights to go along with it.

They want it to look as though a row of Edison lights, 5' high and sitting atop 1/2" black pipe, were sprouting out of a wooden base.

After researching, I have a few ideas of how to do it with rattle canned RMC (see attached picture), but I've been having problems finding cross style Rigid Conduit Bodies... most seem to be (at most) Tees.

Otherwise, my plan was to use Leviton lamp holders fitted into a 1-1/4"x1/2 bell reducer, connect that to the 1/2" RMC, and through the wood base. Below, I'd connect each pipe to the rigid bodies, a short nipple down to a floor flange, and 6" gal pipe connecting it to the rigid body next in line.

I hope this makes sense.

Please let me know if I'm on the right track or if there's an easier or safer method.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can give.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying at real electrical supply houses? Home Depot won't have it...

Comment: So far, I’ve only been doing research and price checking online...leaving me to HD, Lowes, Grainger, etc., but I’ll check the local electrical supply house tomorrow.

Comment: What's a rattle canned RMC? Cheap plastic pipe spray painted flat black? Google suggests: Ready Mixed Concrete, Royal Military College, Resource Monitoring and Control, Robert Morris College, Risk Management Committee

Comment: I like your sketch style, reminds me of something I'd find in a notebook in Myst.

Comment: Rattle canned RMC? Spray painted Rigid Metal Conduit.

Answer (score 1):

Just a possible alternative, if I read you right the conduit bodies in the box are out of sight.  Mount a piece of unistrut on the back wall of your box, and clamp the rigid pipes to the unistrut with strut clamps.

Put a 5' wireway in the box fastened to the base or back of the box.  The pipes will come in the top of the wireway.

[image: 5' wireway]

You should really consider using low voltage lights, this just makes everything safer and gives you much more flexibility.  You can find low voltage lamps that will fit the Edison base, or just use a different base.  You could do this without the wireway if you were so inclined - just splice the 12V wires in your wooden box.  You could epoxy the sockets in the black pipe if so inclined.  You could use actual black pipe with floor flanges.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely more options to consider. Otherwise, I’m on somewhat of the right track/ thinking?

Comment: @sean, lots of possibilities, but if you take away one idea, let it be the low voltage idea.  Safety first.

Comment: Low voltage is definitely something I'd like to consider, but it's a touch beyond my expertise level and will take a bit more research.

Comment: @sean - I think you'll find it very easy, if you can wire speakers you can wire low voltage lights.  Any method you can use with line voltage is OK with low voltage, but things you can do with low voltage would be dangerous with line voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Try Appleton x50A this is aluminum 1/2" X conduit body several online stores carry them under $10 each.
Iron will cost more almost double the cost, Appleton x17. To help your search type conduit body type x , I found these in a few seconds.

Comment: Oh, that’s exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Sean thanks are nice but an up vote or accepted answer will let others know there is a solution to your answer.

Comment: Up voting everything that's helpful, but not showing yet since I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Legit hard piping it for a show is kinda overboard.

I'd build a base out of 2x4s and plywood painted matte black (whatever's going to make it moveable *and* not fall over) with a plain junction box inside (and some weights), using cables going to floor flanges screwed down where I want lights, and drill a hole for each cable in the plywood base.

It will be lit (a dimmer is key here).

And it will be galvanized pipes standing there like you want. That's all they *need* to see and *will* see. Unless you're looking for nods from a mysterious pipe fitter in the audience afterwards...